# Replace character in a string with multiple characters, all possible combinations

Tags: string, language-agnostic, cross-platform

I'll explain by example and desired outcome.

Say I have the following string as a base: abcdwx

I want to generate all possible combinations of the that are possible when including these variations: "a" -> "1, $, A, @", "b" -> "B", c -> "#, 0, 07, cd, CD, Cd, cD, dd, DD", "w" -> "n, NN, l, L, !, 1, ), (, 0, #, &, %, $, ^, ##, ^^"

So, for example, possible combinations would include 1bcd##x abDDd!x and aBcDdNNx

Googling led me to this (not quite what I want) Ruby code

```
string = "abcdwx"
p = ?a, ?b, ?c, ?d, ?w, ?x
q = [ ?1, ?$, ?A, ?@ ], [ ?B ], [ ?#, ?0 ], [ ?d ], [ ?l ], [ ?n, ?N ]

replacements = Hash.new { |h, e| Array e }.tap do |h|
p.zip( q ).each { |p, q| h[p] = p, *Array( q ) }
end
#=> {"a"=>["1", "$", "A", "@"], "b"=>["B"], "c"=>["#", "0"], "d"=>["d"], "w"=>["l"], "x"=>["n", "N"]}

puts string.split( '' ).map( &replacements.method( :[] ) ).reduce( &:product ).map { |e|
e.flatten.join
}
```

which I'm able to use for single-character replacements, but it gives me

```
warning: '?' just followed by NN is interpreted as a conditional operator, put a space after '?'
```

and

```
syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting ']'
```

when I try to do, say, "a" -> "##" or "a" -> "A0"

The method of doing what I'm after doesn't need to be Ruby (or even a script), I just thought that there might be an easy solution to this syntax error problem that I don't understand because I don't know coding.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was change ?## to '?##', ?NN to '?NN', etc.